# Swift CGContext Aspect Fit

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have two image views, one with an image, another with an image defined with CGContext methods, both with the same image size and image view size, on top of each other. In the storyboard, I can set both image views to "Aspect Fit", so users on different devices can still see the image. However, when I go to draw something on the overlaid second image view, it does not scale it accordingly (or relative to the first image view, even though they are the same size). How do I go about making the second image in the overlaid image view the same scale as the image below?

Example Code:

```
import CoreGraphics
import UIKit

class Map: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var drawnImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

        let data = grabData()
        print(data!)

        var img = UIImage(named: "floor1")
        print(img!.size)
        imageView.image = img

        img = draw(imageView.bounds.size, data: data!)
        print(img!.size)
        drawnImageView.image = img
        for c in drawnImageView.constraints {
            if c.identifier == "constraintImageHeight" {
                c.constant = img!.size.height * drawnImageView.bounds.width / img!.size.width;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

func draw(img: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Drawing
    let color = UIColor(red: 0.67, green: 0.4, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)

    var y = 0
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        let b = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), size: CGSize(width: 1200, height: 1))
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, b)
        y += 30
    }

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

**Update 1:**
(replace after '//Drawing')
If you load with iPhone 5 simulator, it doesn't show up in the same place in relation to the photo as it does in the iPhone 6 simulator.

```
func draw(size: CGSize, data: [TotalLine]) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let screen: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let x = screen.size.width, y = screen.size.height

    // Drawing
    //let color = UIColor(red: 0.67, green: 0.4, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1)
    let color = UIColor.redColor()
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)

    let line = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (x/16), y: (y*0.502)), size: CGSize(width: (x/20), height: 2))
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, line)
    let test = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: x, height: y))
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, test)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

**Update 2:**
iPhone 6: 
[image: iPhone 6]

iPhone 5: 
[image: iPhone 5]

I want that red line to show up in between the rooms, like in the iPhone 6 screenshot. In the iPhone 5, it is slightly lower.

**Update 3:**
Printing image views:
*iPhone 5:*

> **Drawn Image View**: frame = (0 0; 600 536);
>   **Image View**: frame = (0 0; 600 536);

*iPhone 6:*

> **Drawn Image View:** frame = (0 0; 600 536);
>   **Image View:** frame = (0 0; 600 536);

Comment: What is `x` and `y` in your udpated code? there are no defines nor initial values provided. Have you removed `for` loop altogether? What exactly is wrong on iPhone 5 in comparison to iPhone 6?

Comment: print imageView's frame for both devices right before you call `draw` method and provide the output here

Comment: Updated in question, **Update 3**

Comment: @alexburtnik any idea what is going on?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but no ideas for now and I cannot reproduce if unfortunately. If you have a test project with this issue, just share it with me and I'll probably fix it

Comment: @alexburtnik what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Create a new project with a single viewController, add two imageViews one over another just as you did in your main project and copy your code. Make sure the issue is still reproduced and give me a link to dropbox, github or whatever.

Comment: @alexburtnik Well... I found out what I was doing wrong. For width and length of the line I wanted, I was using it in proportion to the screen width and height. Since I switched it over to aspect fit, all I had to do was make the values say something like: `CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)`. Thanks for spending the time with the problem, though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm, I should have guessed the reason. Anyway, I'm glad you fixed it ;)

Comment: @alexburtnik It's always the stupid mistakes. Looking at the same code for a week gets hard to tell what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size)
```

with this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

It's not clear why do you use 100 and 1200 harcoded values. if your original image is big enough (higher than 3000 or wider than 1200), your lines won't fill the whole image. Also you don't actually need the original image to create overlay. You just need to know the size, right? Try this method instead:

```
func createLinesImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    let color = UIColor(red: 0.67, green: 0.4, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1)
    context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(2.0)

    var y = CGFloat(0)
    while y < size.height {
        let lineRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: size.width, height: 1)
        context.stroke(lineRect)
        y += 30
    }

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

Now, If you want to draw lines only over the original image, call your method like this:

```
imageView2.image = createLinesImage(size: originalImage.size)
```

[image]

If you need to fill the whole imageView with lines, even if there are blank zones for your original image, use this line:

```
imageView2.image = createLinesImage(size: imageView2.bounds.size)
```

[image]

Comment: UIScreen doesn't have the member "main"

Comment: Are you using swift 2? Try UIScreen.mainScreen().scale then

Comment: Doesn't work. All it ends up doing is moving the drawn image over a few hundred pixels...

Comment: Would be great if you add a screenshot of your problem. I've tried your code and it looks just as you implement it. Original image below and a programmatically created image over it, which contains a bunch of horizontal lines. Is that really what you expect? https://snag.gy/j6woR3.jpg

Comment: Yeah I just put the horizontal lines in so it would be easier to view the changes. It's basically a mapping system for indoors, I have to draw lines in the hallways of the building. (same code as before) http://pasteboard.co/e9vmls8T2.png

Comment: Ok, now I see your problem. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Still not doing what I want it to do. I put a better example in my question.